# matlab for loop: fastest and most efficient method to reproduce large matrix

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, for-loop, copy

My data is a 2096x252 matrix of `double` values. I need a `for` loop or an equivalent which performs the following:
Each time the matrix is reproduced the first array is deleted and the second becomes the first. When the loop runs again, the remaining matrix is reproduced and the first array is deleted and the next becomes the first and so on. 
I've tried using `repmat` but it is too slow and tedious when dealing with large matrices (2096x252).

Example input:

```
1 2 3 4
3 4 5 6
3 5 7 5
9 6 3 2
```

Desired output:

```
1 2 3 4
3 4 5 6
3 5 7 5
9 6 3 2
3 4 5 6
3 5 7 5
9 6 3 2
3 5 7 5
9 6 3 2
9 6 3 2
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your final matrix will be of size `2197656 x 252`, which I think would be over 4.4GB in size. Are you sure memory isn't the limiting factor here, rather than the speed of the algorithm?

Comment: If memory is a limiting factor then could you accommodate the code to splice and dice the data so it wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**
You'll probably have memory issues with large matrices, but that is not the question.

Now, to the business:
For a given matrix `A`, the straightforward approach with the `for` loop would be:

```
[N, M] = size(A);
B = zeros(sum(1:N), M);
offset = 1;
for i = 1:N
    B(offset:offset + N - i, :) = A(i:end, :);
    offset = offset + size(A(i:end, :), 1);
end
```

`B` is the desired output matrix.
However, this solution is expected to be slow as well, because of the `for` loop.

**Edit**: preallocated `B` instead of dynamically changing size (this optimization should achieve a slight speedup).

Comment: I think you're too modest, preallocating B is likely to achieve a huge speedup if the final matrix is as big as OP indicates.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, I haven't tested it for large matrices, so I can only guess...

Comment: @eitanT. Thanks it worked!!! Are there any other more efficient alternatives instead of the for loop?

Comment: @BernardUntalanJr Nothing comes up at the moment, but I'm thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally with Matlab it is much faster to pre-allocate a large array than to build it incrementally.  When you know in advance the final size of the large array there's no reason not to follow this general advice.

Something like the following should do what you want.  Suppose you have an array `in(nrows, ncols)`; then

```
indices = [0 nrows:-1:1];
out = zeros(sum(indices),ncols);
for ix = 1:nrows
    out(1+sum(indices(1:ix)):sum(indices(1:ix+1)),:) = in(ix:end,:);
end
```

This worked on your small test input.  I expect you can figure out what is going on.

Whether it is the fastest of all possible approaches I don't know, but I expect it to be much faster than building a large matrix incrementally.

Comment: I think you can avoid calling `sum` every iteration by computing `cumsum(indices)` before the loop, and picking the next element from the pre-calculated `cumsum` vector in each iteration.

Comment: @EitanT: yes, you could indeed do that.

Comment: I apologize. I'm still a neophyte at matlab. I was unsuccessful in executing your code. Could you elaborate a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: @BernardUntalanJr. Can you be more specific about the way in which you were unsuccessful ?  Have you tried executing it one line at a time on a small test matrix such as the one in your question ?

Comment: I input the following codes in addition to what you specified nrows=size(indices,2)                                  ncols=size(indices,1)                                          Matlab returns the following:                               Undefined function or variable 'in'.

Comment: @BernardUntalanJr. No, no, no, no, no.  `in` is a name I used for the input array, replace that with the name of your input array.  `ncols` and `nrows` are `size(in,1)` and `size(in,2)` which you could get by executing `[nrows, ncols] = size(in)`.

Comment: @BernardUntalanJr. glad to hear it, we'd both better get back to work now, SO is complaining that we're getting too chummy.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Good day to you. On my side of the world, I'm going back to bed. Ill get back to my project in the morning:)